# Error message "Requiring Clutter, version 1.0" displayed and Gnome-Shell refuses to start

Tags: 11.10, gnome

I'm having some problems with gnome-shell. I downloaded from the Ubuntu repository (not ricotz-testing), and typing `gnome-shell --replace` I get this (I removed some repetitions :) ):

```
alecive@calliope:~$ gnome-shell --replace

(gnome-shell:4052): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_value_get_string: assertion `value->type == GCONF_VALUE_STRING' failed

(gnome-shell:4052): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_value_get_string: assertion `value->type == GCONF_VALUE_STRING' failed

(gnome-shell:4052): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_value_get_string: assertion `value->type == GCONF_VALUE_STRING' failed
    JS ERROR: !!! Exception was: Error: Requiring Clutter, version 1.0: Typelib file for namespace 'CoglPango', version '1.0' not found
    JS ERROR: !!! lineNumber = '0'
    JS ERROR: !!! fileName = '"gjs_throw"'
    JS ERROR: !!! stack = '"("Requiring Clutter, version 1.0: Typelib file for namespace 'CoglPango', version '1.0' not found")@gjs_throw:0
@/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/environment.js:9
"'
    JS ERROR: !!! message = '"Requiring Clutter, version 1.0: Typelib file for namespace 'CoglPango', version '1.0' not found"'
    JS ERROR: !!! Exception was: Error: Requiring Clutter, version 1.0: Typelib file for namespace 'CoglPango', version '1.0' not found
    JS ERROR: !!! lineNumber = '0'
    JS ERROR: !!! fileName = '"gjs_throw"'
    JS ERROR: !!! stack = '"("Requiring Clutter, version 1.0: Typelib file for namespace 'CoglPango', version '1.0' not found")@gjs_throw:0
@/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/environment.js:9
"'
    JS ERROR: !!! message = '"Requiring Clutter, version 1.0: Typelib file for namespace 'CoglPango', version '1.0' not found"'
Avviso del window manager: Log level 32: Execution of main.js threw exception: Error: Requiring Clutter, version 1.0: Typelib file for namespace 'CoglPango', version '1.0' not found
```

Someone could help me in getting gnome-shell running? I'm experiencing very annoying behaviors and I really wish to get it on my desktop! :(

To clarify - I know how to log in into gnome-shell from the login screen, but gnome-shell systematically crashes the desktop. So, to see what errors it gives me, I login into unity environment and then I type `gnome-shell --replace`

Moreover, I already used gnome-shell since its natty version and my video-card fully support it. This seems to be a library issue rather than a simple problem related to my ignorance. I think the last two lines of the code prompted above, you can see some dependency.

PS: For the record, I'm on Ubuntu Oneiric 11.10 32bit :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message "Requiring Clutter, version 1.0: Typelib file for namespace 'CoglPango', version '1.0' not found" indicates that a library is missing -

The likely culprit is `gir1.2-cogl-1.0`

Therefore, to install this:

```
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-cogl-1.0
```

If it is says it is already installed - try forcing a reinstall.

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install gir1.2-cogl-1.0
```

It is perhaps also wise to reinstall (or force reinstall) clutter using the package `gir1.2-clutter-1.0`

Comment: This was necessary for me: `apt install gir1.2-clutter-1.0 gir1.2-clutter-gst-3.0 gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0` (18.04)

Answer (score 0):

try opening up gnome-tweak-tool and unchecking nautilus handle desktop see if that helps!
there is also ricotz/testing ppa which is very up to date and is stable..........for the moment!
you could add it do update and dist-upgrade and then disable it after reboot!

Comment: Thanks bmbaker, but the solution given by fossfreedom worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

After installing `gir1` packages with `sudo apt install gir1.2-gtop-2.0 gir1.2-nm-1.0 gir1.2-clutter-1.0`,
type `Alt + F2` and input `r` in the prompt. This will reboot the **gnome-shell** and satisfy the dependency.